# Compiler macro to compare byte size of types

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, c++17

Can this if-statement be replaced with a `#if ....` macro?
Possibly without having to include (too many) extra headers.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
///Parse a string to obtain a fixed width type
inline uint64_t stou64(const std::string& in) {
    if (sizeof(unsigned long) == sizeof(uint64_t)) {
        return std::stoul(in);
    } else {
        return std::stoull(in);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `if constexpr` instead of macros?

Comment: Use [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if).

Comment: Note: You are not comparing the byte size of types but the size in chars. On various DSPs a char is 2 bytes while `sizeof(char) == 1` per definition.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow `You are not comparing the byte size of types` Yes he is `but the size in chars` which is always the same. `On various DSPs a char is 2 bytes while sizeof(char) == 1 per definition.` No. `sizeof` is the size in bytes, and char is by definition exactly one byte. You're thinking of DSP  where the size of byte is 16 bits i.e. 2 octets.

Comment: @eerorika Ok, should have said that char is 2 octets for the language-lawyers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need pre-processor macro for this. The function is well-defined regardless of the size, and the compiler is smart enough to optimise the unused branch away completely.

If you want to be sure that the unused branch is removed even with optimisation disabled, you can use [if constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if). Simply add `constexpr` after if in your example.

---

If you don't need to support currently active locale, then consider using `std::from_chars` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this approach (before C++17 `std::from_chars`):

```cpp
template<typename T>
T string_to(const std::string& in);

template<>
int string_to<int>(const std::string& in) {
    return std::stoi(in);
}

template<>
unsigned string_to<unsigned>(const std::string& in) {
    return std::stol(in);
}

template<>
long string_to<long>(const std::string& in) {
    return std::stol(in);
}

template<>
long long string_to<long long>(const std::string& in) {
    return std::stoll(in);
}

template<>
unsigned long string_to<unsigned long>(const std::string& in) {
    return std::stoul(in);
}

template<>
unsigned long long string_to<unsigned long long>(const std::string& in) {
    return std::stoull(in);
}

inline uint64_t stou64(const std::string& in) {
    return string_to<uint64_t>(in);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/T57cbq91z

Comment: When `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long` are the same data type, how comes the 2 specializations do not collide? If `uint64_t` is the same of `unsigned long` and of `unsigned long long`, how does the compiler choose which function/specialization to use?

Comment: they are not same data type. They have same size, but for compiler it is different build in type. Standard library have type definitions for `uint64_t` which specific for given platform and just map respective build in type.

Answer (score 1):

No, your `if` statement is different because both the if and the else path are compiled and must be valid expressions, even if the compiler then optimizes the code to only the path taken. In an `#if` macro only the part that remains is seen by the compiler. The eliminated part doesn't have to be sensical for the given argument.

Since this can be an issue with templates the [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) syntax was added in c++17.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
///Parse a string to obtain a fixed width type
inline uint64_t stou64(const std::string& in) {
    if constexpr (sizeof(unsigned long) == sizeof(uint64_t)) {
        return std::stoul(in);
    } else {
        return std::stoull(in);
    }
}
```

Note: In this specific example it doesn't matter. But why not get used to `if constexpr` anyway?